# Setting/Retrieving $_SESSION and $_COOKIE with AJAX/jQuery on Apache Cordova not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cordova

I've got a problem where I'm using Apache Cordova to build an apps, but session and cookie not working on IOS and Web Browser, but work perfectly on Android

Server Side code: apps.php hosted on cloud server

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');

    if(isset($_GET['saved'])){
    setcookie("mycookie", 'mycontent', time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
    $_SESSION['test'] = 'myid';
    $data = array(true, 'done');
    }
    else if (isset($_GET['getsaved'])) {
    $data = array(true, $_COOKIE['mycookie'], $_SESSION['test']);
    }

    echo isset($data) ? json_encode($data) : '';
?>
```

Client Side code: index.html localhost (Apache Cordova)

```
$(document).on('click', '.saveitem', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.example.com/apps.php?saved",
      type: 'POST',
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: 'json',
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
      }
  });
});

$(document).on('click', '.getsave', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.example.com/apps.php?getsaved",
      type: 'POST',
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: 'json',
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data[1]+', '+data[2]);
      }
  });
});
```

Output for Android: *mycontent, myid*

Output on IOS and Web Browser: *undefined, undefined*

Comment: I found out that I'm not getting same session_id every time I'm sending a request, is there a way to fix that?